# URL Decoder not working

Tags: android

I am trying to decode a name string which contains apostrophe. This name string is being parsed in an XML parser, so what I want to do is that the apostrophe should be displayed normally, rather than being displayed as `&#039;`. I tried using the `URLDecoder.decode(myString, "UTF-*");` to decode it but to no avail. From one solution posted on StackOverflow I found that we need to use the `URLDecoder.decode()` twice. However, even that is not working. The code that I am using is:

```
try {
        temp = URLDecoder.decode("Wing&#039;s", "UTF-8");
        nameOrg = URLDecoder.decode(temp, "UTF-8");
    } 
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

At the end it should display `Wing&#039;s` as `Wing's`, but it is displaying the same string. Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just `decode` it using  `Html.fromHtml(String source)`,

```
Spanned temp = Html.fromHtml("Wing&#039;s");
Log.d("decoded", temp.toString());
```

`Output` - Wing's